# create a function with proper scope

Tags: powershell, scope

I need to create a script to authenticate to a remote PC and access to PS console. It actually works, but I need to execute a number of commands when I need to terminate this session.

So I create a function STOP to be called to terminate the session, but it can't be used.
Is this a problem of scope (because it's inside an if statement)? If I manually create the same function and then I try to call it... It works!

```
# get connection parameters
$credential = Get-Credential -Credential xxx
$remote_PC = Read-Host "Insert the server name or IP (Q to abort): "
# connect
if (someKindOfCheck) {
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $remote_PC -Credential $credential
    # some commands
    function STOP {
        Exit-PSSession;
        # some commands
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter-PSSession is only for interactive use (once you've entered that session it only takes input from the console). 
The only way I can think of that would make this work "automagically" would be to create a custom remoting session on the target machine that implements a proxy function for Exit-PSSession,  and put your commands in that function.

Answer (score 3):

I've come across a similar issue before, and I resolved it by creating  a `New-PSSession` and assigning it to a varialbe, I then use the `Invoke-Command` with `-Session` option to execute the required commands.